# Access View State in ashx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project, i have on ashx handler file, 
I want to make some `ViewState` data in my ashx file and  then check it on .cs file

How can i achieve this as i can't access `ViewState` object in my ashx file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot access the data of page in Ashx file because it handler and get executed when the request to page take place.

Instead of viewstate you can make use of Session boject liek this

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
  {
      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
           context.Session["sessionvariable"] = "value";
     }
  }
```

or to just readonly acces to session object

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
   public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
   {
       ctx.Response.Write(ctx.Session["fred"]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewState` is specific to the page and is contained in a hidden element on the client-side of the page.

I would suggest the `Session` or `Cache` object as a better solution